# How to connect two databases, one with new user registration data, and another with the data they enter

Tags: php, mysql, database, web-applications, xampp

I am doing a web application where from the beginning a new user is registered (the registration data is kept in the database no.1), then
 on the next page he inserts a number that is stored in another database (no.2). These data (from the database no.2) are displayed in an application table, but the problem is that no matter which user they log in at the moment in the application, the data table displays all the users who entered something number in database number 2, while the table should only display the data of the currently logged-in.

Comment: Why would you create a separate database for users?

Comment: Good question you asked, I think I should add the user data table to the same database where the numbers are entered.